# Remove all children nodes and get the content with simpleXML

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

I want to get the content of all children node in a one varable. For example :

```
<p><distinct type="twitter-retweet"><ident>RT</ident>
            <addressingTerm><addressMarker>@</addressMarker><addressee type="twitter-account"
                ref="https://twitter.com/LePG 35022597"
            >LePG</addressee></addressingTerm>:</distinct> A 07h50,
              <addressingTerm><addressMarker>@</addressMarker><addressee type="twitter-account"
              ref="#cmr-politweets-p80820758">JLMelenchon</addressee></addressingTerm> est
          l'invité des #4vérités sur <distinct type="twitter-hashtag"><ident>#</ident><rs
              ref="https://twitter.com/search?q=%23France2&amp;src=hash"
          >France2</rs></distinct>. Nous live-tweeterons. #Chômage <distinct
            type="twitter-hashtag"><ident>#</ident><rs
              ref="https://twitter.com/search?q=%23Municipales2014&amp;src=hash"
              >Municipales2014</rs></distinct></p>
```

I want to have in output this sentence :

> "RT @LePG A 07h50, @JLMelenchon est l'invité des #4vérités sur #France2. Nous live-tweeterons. #Chomage #Municipale2014"

The problem is when i use asXML(), i have also the nodes in the variable.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While it might seem a bit of a cop out, if you're not forced to use simpleXML, and you can obtain the XML as a string: I would like to suggest simply using "strip_tags" https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php

Otherwise you'll need to recursively parse the children to build the string. I'll update with the recursive function if necessary.